# clojure unsequential let

Tags: clojure, scheme

it seem like clojure's `let` is sequential and would correspond to a scheme `let*` .
Does clojure have an unsequential binding mechanism like scheme's `let`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `binding` macro is parallel not sequential.

See: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/binding

Comment: thanks (defn test []
  (binding [a 0
        b (+ a 1)]
       b))

Answer (score 2):

letfn is a parallel binding form for functions that exists to allow people to write mutually recursive local functions. It's not quite as general as you seek though it can be used in a pinch.

```
user> (letfn [(a [] 4) 
              (b [] c) 
              (c [] a)] 
       (a))
4
```

Binding can be used so long as you are assigning values to things in vars and want dynamic scoping

```
user> (def ^:dynamic x 4)
#'user/x
user> (defn foo [] x)
#'user/foo
user> (binding [x 8] (+ x (foo)))
16 ; the value of x that gets called by foo is modified by the caller
   ; yielding 16 instead of 12

user> (binding [x 8 a 7] (+ x (foo)))
; Evaluation aborted.
Unable to resolve var: a in this context
```

if you try to use parallel bindings the dynamic scoping will give different results than let* would in Scheme

```
user> (def ^:dynamic a 2)
#'user/a
user> (binding [x 8 a 7] (+ x a))
15
user> (binding [x 8 a (+ x 2)] (+ x a))
14 ; this would be 18 if the binding of x to 8 had been used
   ; instead the root value of 4 was used.
```

In general It is most common to bind sequentially or use nested `let`s if required.

Answer (score 1):

`binding` doesn't give you the same capability as a parallel `let` because it depends on the existence of bindings. As mentioned `letfn` will work as long as you don't mind wrapping your values in functions. Another solution is to write a parallel let using a macro:

```
(defmacro letp 
  [bindings & exprs]
  (let [bindings (partition 2 bindings)
        vars     (->> bindings (map first) vec)
        values   (->> bindings (map second))]
    `((fn ~vars ~@exprs)
      ~@values)))
```

So the following holds:

```
(def a 7)

(letp [a 5 b a] b)
;;=> 7
```